# Retaining namespace and variable values after script execution

Tags: python, python-2.7

I wrote some code in Matlab where the scope of variables executed in scripts is retained in the "workspace". The data I'm working on is very large, and so each execution of a script requires 20-30 minutes to produce the necessary results. The advantage of Matlab was that after execution, if I desired to add code to the end of the script, I can execute it to the result variables rather that have to re-run the code from the start.

How can I do something similar in Python where the values of variables are retained from one script execution to the next?

Comment: https://ipython.org/notebook.html

Comment: I've rephrased your question and title to better capture what I think you meant. Feel free to roll back if I misunderstood something.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the variables out to some persistent storage on disk at the end of execution, such as with the [shelve](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html) or [json](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/json.html) modules. Then add some logic to the start of your script that attempts to read in the variables from the persistent storage and restore the workspace, and will rerun the calculations if the load fails.

Answer (score 1):

You really want to run an interactive python shell.  That is really what you are doing in MATLAB, all the scripts are running inside the same MATLAB shell.  That is why the variable persist across runs, because the shell is preserving them.

The difference with python is that it has two ways to run scripts: in a python shell or standalone.  You are running them standalone in python, which isn't an option in MATLAB.

If you want something as close as possible to what you are doing in MATLAB, just wrap the code in your script in a function, fire up a python shell, and run the function.

However, this isn't usually the best approach for long-running, repeated code like you are doing.  The much better approach would be to use the IPython/Jupyter notebook.  This interface allows you to run parts of your code selectively, reorganize parts, and many other useful features.  It also has a feature that lets you automatically preserve specific variables across sessions.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correctly.

I think the best choice is using python shell directly without writing script in file then running it.

2nd choice is pickling or object serialization:

> “Pickling” is the process whereby a Python object hierarchy is
>   converted into a byte stream, and “unpickling” is the inverse
>   operation, whereby a byte stream is converted back into an object
>   hierarchy.

["Python object serialization"](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html)

Comment: Sure that's possible, but I don't think it's very practical if the calculations are complex enough to take 20-30 minutes.

Comment: I think it depends on format and visualization of code rather than running timing.